# Adding a progress bar and/or internal window to program. (How To?)

Tags: c++

I would like to take this code and add a progress bar to show the progress (BUUUUH), and also add a window inside the main one showing the names of the files being currently moved. I am totally lost right now on how to do this. I would love help if anyone can offer some.

```
enter code here
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "Back Up";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR lpszArgument,
                int nFunsterStil)

{

HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground =  GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       "Back It Up",       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       545,                 /* The programs width */
       300,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM         lParam)
{
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{

       case WM_CREATE:
{
       CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Pictures"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 50, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Music"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 120, 50, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Videos"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 100, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL); 

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Fun Times"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 120, 100, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 4, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Programs"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 150, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 5, NULL, NULL); 

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("(WiP)"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 120, 150, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 6, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Quit"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 200, 180, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 7, NULL, NULL);  

    CreateWindow(TEXT("Static"), TEXT("Choose what you would like to back up from the          options on the left."
                 " Remember this program is still in developmentso bugs and UI issues are to be expected." 
                 " Future addons include Progress bar, activity terminal, and customizable locations."
                 " Also please do not disturb the program while it is running, it will not respond."), 
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                 220, 50, 280, 150,
                 hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Back Up All"),
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                 20, 14, 180, 25,
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 8, NULL, NULL);   
    break;
}

case WM_COMMAND:
  {
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
       system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/pictures E:/pictures /e /r:3 /w:0");
   }
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
      system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/music E:/music /e /r:3 /w:0");                   
   }
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3) {
      system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/videos E:/videos /e /r:3 /w:0");                   
   }
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 4) {
      system("robocopy C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/fun times e:/fun times  /e /r:3 /w:0");                   
   }
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 5) {
      system("robocopy C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/programs e:/programs /e /r:3 /w:0");                   
   } /*
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 6) {
      system("robocopy C:/Users/jacob/documents e:/documents /e /r:3 /w:0");                   
   } */
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 7) {
          PostQuitMessage(0);
   }
   if (LOWORD(wParam) == 8 ) {
      system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/pictures E:/pictures /e /r:3 /w:0");
      system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/music E:/music /e /r:3 /w:0");
      system("robocopy C:/users/jacob/videos E:/videos /e /r:3 /w:0");
      system("robocopy C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/fun times e:/fun times  /e /r:3 /w:0");
      system("robocopy C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/programs e:/programs /e /r:3 /w:0");
   }

   break;
   }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: There are reasons why you can't ask _"How to"_ questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add a progress bar to show the progress

Read up about the [Progress Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760818.aspx) control.

You already know how to create a window and subwindows.  Creating a ProcessBar is no different than creating a Button, or any other control, using `CreateWindow/Ex()`.

> add a window inside the main one showing the names of the files being currently moved.

That is more difficult.  You are executing an external command to move the files, so you don't have direct access to its status information.  You would have to replace `system()` with `CreateProcess()` so you can redirect its output:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Once you have access to the output, you can parse it as needed and display it however you want, such as in a multi-line [Edit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control, a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control, a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control, etc.

Alternatively, use [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a recursive loop to iterate the source folder yourself, using [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CopyFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as needed.  Then you will have direct access to each filename and progress information for each file.  Then you do not need to use a redirected robocopy process anymore, and have more control over the iterating and copying.